# PHP mysqli prepared statements and transactions within a foreach loop not working

Tags: php, mysqli, foreach, transactions, prepared-statement

I am currently working on a server with PHP version 5.3.24

Using mysqli with prepared statements.

I'm trying to implement transactions for multiple queries, so if one of them fails everything is rolled back.

I digged as much as i could in SO answers but none of the ones i tried seems to work, not sure what am i doing wrong.

**Code**:

```
$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE); 

$query = "UPDATE table SET value = ? WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare( $query );


foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    $stmt->bind_param( 'si', $value, $key );
    $stmt->execute();       
} 

if (!$mysqli->commit()) {
    $mysqli->rollback();
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

The loop in the example has around 10 iterations, no matter if i set the first to fail or any other the queries get executed in all but the wrong one.

Comment: http://www.php.net/mysqli.commit  see the first note by a user named *Lorenzo*; that's directly related to your question.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Thanks for the response, in order to apply that to a prepared statement context where should i place `? null : $all_query_ok=false;` ? right after `$stmt->execute();` ?

Comment: That's correct. like this `if($stmt->execute()){$ok==TRUE}`

Comment: Unfortunately is not working, all of the other rows gets updated but the one who is wrong.

Comment: I hope you are not assuming that this will fail on a query which didn't update anything? This fails only on queries which failed to execute. I.e. They have any error

Comment: I was updating the wrong file, managed to make it work, thanks!